# How would I check if a landmark isn't being shown on Dlib face tracking?

Tags: python, dlib

I'm doing some face tracking with Dlib, and it works fine. But I also need it to check if the landmarks aren't being shown anymore. I have two variables on the location of the landmarks (x, y) and I'm printing them. I wrote a line that goes

```
if x == None:
    print('Landmarks not shown.')
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this help if x is None:?